# Ansible - combining string with an existing variable to register into another variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I want to combine a fact set with `set_facts` with a string variable and register it as a new variable.

I think, we cannot register a new variable in an Ansible playbook. So can I use `set_facts` again to combine a previous `set_fact` with an existing variable?

I am not sure about the syntax here.

Here is an example:

```
- vars:
    list_1: usera,userb,userc
```

```
- set_fact:
    list_2: "userd,usere,userf"
```

Now I want to combine both of the string with comma in between and get a variable value like this:

```
final_list: usera,userb,userc,userd,usere,userf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set_fact:
  final_list: "{{ list_1 }},{{ list_2 }}"
```

or use the string concatenation operator

```
set_fact:
  final_list: "{{ list1 ~ ',' ~ list_2 }}"
```

Comment: i tried the first option and it is giving me result like this "final_list": "[u'usera,userb,userc'],userd,usere,userf". I don't know why it is showing up the [u' ] in the result.  :(

Comment: Then use it on the code **you posted in the question**. Or ask another question about the code you are running. Because they are not the same.

Comment: Okay. let me ask another question for more clarity